# Using counts and sum in aggregate query

Tags: mysql

**UPDATE: seems like force alarm and I misinterpreted my result set and actually query returns what it is supposed to return. Oops. Thanks a lot to everyone for helping!**

What's wrong with my query? The incorrect results are being produced.

```
SELECT
    utm_source as source,
    utm_medium as medium,
    utm_campaign as campaign,
    utm_content as content,
    COUNT(order_id) as orders,
    COUNT(DISTINCT _customer_user) as customers,
    SUM(_order_total) as revenue,
    SUM(_refund_amount) as refunded,
    SUM(_order_total) - SUM(_refund_amount) as net,
    (SUM(_order_total) - SUM(_refund_amount))/COUNT(DISTINCT _customer_user) as 'average ticket'
FROM wp_realtime_utm_tracking_utms
GROUP BY source, medium, campaign, content
```

Comment: It would help to show a relevant sample of expected results, actual results, and source data that led to those results... but my initial guess would be that `COUNT(DISTINCT _customer_user)` is the wrong divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try this query?

```
SELECT utm_source as source, utm_medium as medium, utm_campaign as campaign, utm_content as content, COUNT(order_id) as orders, COUNT(DISTINCT _customer_user) as customers, SUM(_order_total) as revenue, SUM(_refund_amount) as refunded, (SUM(_order_total) - SUM(_refund_amount)) as net, ((SUM(_order_total) - SUM(_refund_amount))/COUNT(DISTINCT _customer_user)) as 'average ticket' FROM wp_realtime_utm_tracking_utms GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
```